# Solve an expression involving a summation

Tags: probability

Suppose we have the following equation.

$$\sum_{x=1}^n (0.4)(0.6)^{x - 1} \geq 0.6$$

I seek to find a value for $n$.

I can't show any attempts to solve this since I don't know where to start. Is there some kind of a theorem that I am missing? or perhaps some the inequality above can be converted to another form that it is easier to solve?

Comment: It is $$0.4(1+0.6+0.6^2+...)$$

Comment: Well I don't think that's entirely helpful since then I will have to keep expanding until the result reaches above the desired value. I know what sigma means, I just need a way to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method 1:** Using the formula for geometric series, we have
$$0.4 \times \frac{1-0.6^{n}}{1 - 0.6} \geq 0.6$$
Simplifying we have
$$0.6^n \leq 0.4$$
which gives
$$n \geq \frac{\log 0.4}{\log 0.6} > 1$$
and finally
$$n \geq 2$$

---

**Method 2:** Let $S_n = \sum_{x=1}^n 0.4 \times 0.6^{x-1}$ for $n \geq 1$. Note that
$$S_{n+1} - S_n = 0.4 \times 0.6^n > 0$$
and hence
$$S_{n+1} > S_n$$
that is $S_n$ is an increasing sequence. By directly checking
$$S_1 = 0.4 \times 1 = 0.4 < 0.6$$
$$S_2 = 0.4 \times (1+0.6) = 0.64 \geq 0.6$$
Hence $S_n \geq 0.6$ if and only if
$$n \geq 2$$

Comment: Method zero would be to plug in $n=0,1,2,3$.

Comment: But then without knowing $S_n$ is increasing as in method 2, you will have infinitely many cases to check. :P